# Continuous Probability - Bus Arriving

Tags: probability

I am trying to do the following question:

> Number 24 and number 42 buses arrive independently at the corner of
>   Mayeld Road at a random rate of 3 and 4 per hour respectively. You
>   arrive at the bus stop at 10 a.m. What is the probability that it
>   takes at least 20 minutes for a bus (either the 24 and 42 bus) to
>   arrive?

I am kinda of stuck on how to start it. So I've learned about Uniform distribution, normal distribution and exponential distribution. I actually not really sure which one to use here. Could you also explain what sort of problems to apply each distribution to?

If I set up a random variable, what should it denote? The number of minutes pass 10 for a bus to arrive? Or that the 42 and 24 bus arrive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You're looking for the waiting time distribution for either bus, which is exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). This is because you know the bus has equal probability of arriving at any given time in an hour, and that the distribution is memoryless. So the waiting time for a bus has density $f(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$, where $\lambda$ is the rate. To understand the rate, you know that $f(t)dt$ is a probability, so $\lambda$ has units of $1/[t]$. Thus if your bus arrives $r$ times per hour, the rate would be $\lambda=r$. Since the expectation of an exponential distribution is $1/\lambda$, the higher your rate, the quicker you'll see a bus, which makes intuitive sense.

So define $X=\min(B_1,B_2)$, where $B_1$ is exponential with rate $3$ and $B_2$ has rate $4$. It's easy to show the minimum of two independent exponentials is another exponential with rate $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$. Thus you want:

$$P(X>\mbox{20 minutes}) = P(X> 1/3)=1-F(1/3),$$

where $F(t)=1-e^{-t(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)}$.

Comment: How do you get P(X>1/3), what does it mean?

Comment: Also why have you defined   $F(t) = 1 - e^{-t(\lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2})  } $ like this? Shouldn't it match the form of the density function, so
 $F(t) = {\lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2}  }- e^{ -t(\lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2})  } $

Comment: $P(X>1/3)$ because the units you are using are hours, and 20 minutes is 1/3 of an hour.

Comment: $F(t)$ is the cumulative distribution function of the exponential distribution, not the density.